# Not able to access server from specific other server

Tags: networking, server, 18.04

I'm running a VPS with `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64)` accessible with `example000.com`.

Since some hours I'm suddenly not able to access this server from my other server `example111.com`.

`example111.com` can neither access port 80 (webpage) nor port 3306 (MySQL) on `example000.com`.

Access with port 80 results to `Internal Server Error`. Access with port 3306 results to `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out`. Both take some time before I get the error message.

But I'm able to access both ports on `example000.com` from other servers.

It seems like `example111.com` (or its IP) is somewhere blocked on server `example000.com`.

But I can't find the IP blocked anywhere. `/etc/hosts.deny` is empty.

Is there any other place where `example111.com` could be blocked on server `example000.com`?

BTW: I do have SSH access.

Comment: Sounds like a MySQL failure, not a “block”. You’ll want to SSH into your `000` server and confirm the database is still operational.

Comment: @matigo How can I do that?

Comment: Connect to `000` via SSH and see if you can connect to MySQL. If it's running a modern version of Ubuntu, then you can use `sudo mysql`. If it's not running, then you'll want to check the logs in `/var/log/mysql` to see why the database engine is offline 

Comment: @matigo I did and MySQL is working. Any other ideas?